# Delphi XE2 IdTCPClient - How to receive data?

Tags: delphi, indy

Only IdTCPClient Used. (Server is Web Chat. That's Not My Server)

EX) Winsock.GetData -> IdTCPClient.??

Comment: Your question is too broad. Without knowing what kind of data you are trying to read, it is hard to tell you how to read it effectively. Indy has many different reading methods for different kinds of data and situations. You need to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

Use the socket property, it has lots of functions for receiving data, starting with "Read".

Like this:

```
DataAsString := IDTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn;
```

Comment: Use the generalized `IOHandler` property instead of the specialized `Socket` property: `IdTCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLn`